# Video 50% height

Tags: html, css, video

I am currently working on a website where I want on the top to be a slideshow/carousel like thing but with videos instead of pictures instead.

The video should have a width of the full page which is working fine but I can't happen to get it to to adjust the height.

The video is "to big" in height so I am trying to only show half of it.

I tried doing so by limiting the height of the parent div but the video keeps to "overlap" out of that div.

Comment: add your snippet here or any live url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the div of the video. Therefore the div will hide any overflowing content of the div.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there also a way to move the part of the video shown upwards?

Answer (score 0):

I believie you are looking for something like this. It would keep aspect ratio.

```
<div class="container"> 
  <video></video>
</div>

.container {
    padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */
}
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp
Or as Mantas mentiones, do `overflow: hidden`, but that will crop video.